# Как сгенерировать Sign keyHash для Google LogIn

Tags: java, google-authenticator

У меня проблема точно как [описано на англ SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821136/release-signed-android-app-google-plus-login-and-google-map-not-working)

Когда тестирую приложение в версии дебаг то <kbd>Google LogIn</kbd> кнопка работает отлично...

Но как сделал версию релиз, то перестала работать...

Вот человек говорит, что проблема в том, что нужно сгенерировать ключ и дает даже команды которыми это сделать

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl
```

base64

For Example Like this

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias selvin -keystore c:\users\selvin\desktop\selvin.kp | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl base64
```

Для того, чтоб собрать эту команду нужно определить где находится

keytool
androiddebugkey
%HOMEPATH% - это вообще что? 
openssl sha1 -binary
openssl base64

И как понять где найти все эти пути?

Вообще странно, зачем гугл придумал такой изощренный способ на получение...

Помогите разобраться если кто уже делал релиз приложению в котором реализован вход через гугл

ПРАВКА

Команда для получения SHA1

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

И как добавить еще один ключ если там нет кнопки добавить... Там я так понимаю, можно только изменить сущестующий

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это путь до ключа который вы сделали и которым вы будете подписывать приложение для маркета. Дебажный ключ и внешний ключ разработчика имеют разные sha-1 значения, поэтому кнопка и перестала работать

Comment: @АндроидАндроид теперь мне нужно получить новый sha-1 ключ и поменять его в консоли?

Comment: можно просто добавить его, в консоли разрешено использовать их в несколкьих вариантах

Comment: @АндроидАндроид я добавил в вопрос команду которой я получал ключ когда имплементировал кнопку гугла, но если я правльно понимаю, то эта команда опять же вернет мне такой же дебажный ключ, а мне нужно релизный получить, верно?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид и вот насчет того, что можно добавить дополнительно ключи я добавил в вопрос скрин. Там нет кнопки добавить еще... Я так понимаю можно только поменять один на другой... Или не туда смотрю?

Comment: значит не везде можно использовать. в гуглокартах дает право на такое.Да, в команде укажите только путь до релизного ключа, алиас ключа и пароль, который вы придумали

Comment: @АндроидАндроид да, все заработало! Спасибо!